# Prove a function is entire

Tags: complex-analysis

If $g(z)=u(x,y) + i\,v(x,y)$
and $h(z)=a(x,y) + i\,b(x,y)$ are entire
prove that for any $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb C$  - Complex constants.

1. $f(z)= \alpha*g(z) + \beta*h(z)$ is also entire
2. $f(z)= g(z)*h(z)$ is also entire
   and
3. $f(z) = g(h(z))$ is also entire

for 1 I am trying to multiply the complex constant $\alpha=(c+di)$ into the function $g(z)=u+iv$
and the same for the second term. Then separate the Re and Im parts out to apply to the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Setting $\Phi = $Re and $\Sigma =$ Im, once the equations are all multiplied together do not satisfy the C-R equations. I am lost here and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, given any fixed $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{\alpha g(z)-\alpha g(z_0)}{z-z_0}+\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{\beta h(z)-\beta h(z_0)}{z-z_0}$$
$$=\alpha g'(z_0)+\beta h'(z_0)$$
Since $g$ and $h$ are entire, so is $f$ by construction.

The same thing with the second statement. And the third is a little bit different:
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{g(h(z))-g(h(z_0))}{z-z_0}$$
$$=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{g(h(z))-g(h(z_0))}{h(z)-h(z_0)}\frac{h(z)-h(z_0)}{z-z_0}=g'(h(z_0))h'(z_0)$$
As $g$, $h$ are entire, $f$ keeps the same property.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the function is entire iff it is complex differentiable for each point in $\mathbb{C}$.  So, rather than using the CR equations, use the rules regarding derivatives.

More specifically: a) follows from the linearity of differentiation, b) follows from the product rule, and c) follows from the chain rule.